# Is the Lebesgue measure of the boundary of a compact set in R^n necessarily 0?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the Lebesgue measure of the boundary of  a compact set in R^n necessarily 0? If so, how to prove?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

Is false: the fat Cantor sets are a counterexample. Take the interval $[0,1]$ and remove a middle subinterval of length $l<1/3$. Iterate the process with the subintervals. The remaining set is compact, has empty interior and measure $>0$.

Comment: Isn't the Cantor set Closed, and so it contains its boundary, and it is well know that the Lebesgue Measure of the Cantor Set is 0

Comment: @phatty, the **fat** cantor set has measure $>0$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set.